# IP Camera stream in browser

Tags: asp.net, nginx, rtsp, mediaelement.js

I've got several IP Cameras that I want to stream to my web site. They give me H264 rtsp stream.

The idea is to get it working without plugins (other than flash). On Windows server and with low cpu overhead.
So I've decided using MediaElement.js player http://mediaelementjs.com/
It has cross-browser H264 support

My investigation:

Browsers do not support rtsp without plugins
So I use vlc to convert rtsp stream to http:

```
vlc -vvv cam_stream :sout=#http{mux=ffmpeg{mux=flv},dst=:8080/video} :sout-keep
```

I do not use transcoding as it has high CPU usage

I can open this stream in another vlc instance, but not in web browser.

MPEG-DASH is used for streaming. There is nginx-rtmp-module that can broadcast mpeg-dash from a video file.

Can it be used for ip camera stream?
Is there any other solution to display rtsp ip camera stream in web browser?

Any solution on Windows is welcome (I use ASP.NET and IIS). C++/C#/JavaScript solution is also nice

Answer (score 0):

Convert RTSP stream into RTMP, then using flash player open RTMP stream.

As a reference you can check wowza server, which take RTSP as a input and stream it as a RTMP stream to web browser.

[Check this answer as well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33497580/636424)

Comment: Thank you. Can I do this without flash? And/or with some free solution?

Comment: Check for live555 webrtc streaming. But webrtc is not compatible with IE and SAFARI.