# How to stream video over rtsp protocol for Live555 server on web browser

Tags: javascript, html, tcp, video-streaming, rtsp

I am already using **rtsp protocol** to stream video on windows application and Silver-light web application. I have built rtsp server using **Live555 library**, which connects with video source and multicast with different users(clients).

But now I want to stream video source in web browser to **replace silver-light** component. So please some one can help me to do this on web browser.

Is there any standard way/solution to do rtsp video streaming on web browser? Please help me for video streaming over tcp socket on web browser. Currently, I am using **rtsp over tcp protocol** for video streaming.

Comment: have you seen this ? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27203207/what-support-for-live-streaming-does-the-html5-video-element-have

Comment: You might find interesting options in my reply: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44167594/251980

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in 3 ways:

1. Write a plug in for live555 server which converts RTSP stream into RTMP. Then stream RTMP to web browser. From web browser using Flash player open RTMP stream.
2. Use third party server (e.g. wowza) which take RTSP stream from live555 as a input and stream out as RTMP. From web browser using Flash player open RTMP stream.
3. Recently live555 developer has added webrtc streaming in library. You can use this feature for web browser streaming. [live555-webrtc-demo](http://webrtc.live555.com/). This feature stream direct to web browser. But you need webrtc compatible web browser (e.g. firefox, chrome, opera).

I personally used second option as a web browser streaming solution.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks dgate. You have any sample code for  live555-webrtc-demo or any other implementation reference.

Comment: There is no test application given in live555 testProgs. It is still in development phase. For webrtc streaming, you need to understand webrtc API, STUN/TURN/ICE. Refer the link given above as a source. Also check for GenericMediaServer.cpp in live555 source.